# How to simulate GSM network

Tags: gsm, ns-3

I want to simulate a moving cell phones on a high way. I need a simulator to build the GSM network and get the cell phones information during the trip on this road.

I am trying to use ns3, but its very complicated to me (as i am new to this) and i searched for any `hello world` tutorial to get me in, but in vain.

I need help in how to do this with ns3. Or is there any other simple simulators that can do this?. Any tiny tips are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NS3 support LTE and WiMax but does not support GSM.

To do some hello world, you can try

```
./waf --run hello-simulator
```

You could find hello world script at `scratch` folder.

Comment: Yes i know it supports LTE, but i think it also supports GSM but i'm not sure. Can you recommend any other simple simulator?. Thanks

Comment: how about OpenBTS ? But you still need some physical stuff.

Comment: I don't have the ability to get physical stuff :(